# Show a form's response in browser instead of Lotus Notes Tab

Tags: forms, lotus-notes, html-email

this is the first time I work with email forms for Lotus Notes - should the answer be too simple, please forgive me.

What I do is sending an HTML mail with a FORM. Usually Notes opens URLs in such emails in a new browser window - but the email form (or rather the server's response) is opened in a new tab.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body style="width: 600px; padding: 20px; margin: 0px; font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px">
...
<form action="http://server/url/" method="post" target="_blank">
...
<div style="margin-top: 30px; text-align: right; padding-bottom: 30px; border-bottom: 2px solid #CCCCCC">
<input type="submit" value="Send" />
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

PS: Lotus seems to ignore whether a target="_blank" is set or not.

Any suggestions? I know that you can modify the program's behavior when it is your Notes - but as the tab sometimes has other connections settings (e.g. proxy) than the local browser I'd like to change the behavior "by mail".

Thanks for suggestions!
BurninLeo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately browser behavior can't be controlled by the content and needs to be set on the client side.  The target attribute is the only thing you can change.

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted to hear (I hoped for a special attribute that only Notes knows or such ...), but definitely helpful. I can stop searching for solution for the rest of the days now :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Check your browser settings and what happens when you click on a link in the browser. If it normally opens in a new tab, then setting your target doesn't make a difference, as the new tab is the target.

Before tabbed browsing was introduced, it would always open a new window, but now it just opens a new tab.